# Flash Mobile iOS app launches to a blank / empty screen when using an ANE

Tags: ios, flash, mobile, air, air-native-extension

I've been developing a mobile application for Android and iOS for several weeks. It has been built using a single ANE up until this week when I attempted to add a second. This new ANE has native code for the iOS platform and a pure-ActionScript (default) implementation for Android and the simulator. Android and the simulator work fine with the new ANE, but when I attempt to run my app on iOS all I see is a black screen.

I'm able to export a release build without any errors and I'm able to execute the fast-debug build but both result in the same empty screen. (The debug build also fails to connect to Flash Builder's debugger.)

I'm using Flash Builder 4.6 and Flex SDK 4.6. My iOS SDK is version 5.0.

Anyone encounter this before? I'm running out of ideas. :)

Comment: Check the crash logs on the iOS device. If I recall correctly, you can do this by synching the device w/iTunes and then using something called iPhone Configuration Utility. I think this utility comes w/XCode so you might need Mac OS.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the crash log doesn't have anything useful. (The app doesn't actually crash.)

All the Console shows when I launch my app is:
`May  2 13:29:45 Labs-iPad-3 kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[6944] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
May  2 13:29:45 Labs-iPad-3 kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[6944] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/0BC1F767-F3D3-4D63-AAD2-A5542A106794 [69] (sandbox)`

Comment: Interestingly enough, updating to the AIR 3.2 SDK temporarily fixed this issue for me and I was able to launch my app. Unfortunately, a few builds later I am back with the empty/black screen.